# SQL: One table, different names for columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have many data types which are very similar, except for a small number of columns which logically have different names (but the same data types). I want to store everything in one table.

Right now my idea is simply to give a generic name to some of the columns (e.g. "custom_data_1" etc.) and in a different table remember for each data type what its column names are. This should work, but I wonder if there's a more structured way (that will make queries easier and will feel less dirty) to achieve the same effect (in MySQL or SQLite).

Comment: Do you mean something like [Entity–attribute–value model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278025/sql-one-table-different-names-for-columns)

Comment: your logical database model should depend on the conceptual model (which is defined by business logic) + technical auxillary entitites. Seem like you're going to construct something scary and make your business logic dependend on db model. That's not a way to go. Also, read about database normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are storing different things, you should store them in different tables**. You can then later create a view to have something that's easy to query.

The advantage is that each table has its own objects, and you can easily add/remove/rename columns to it. What if your type1 needs 2 extra columns, but type2 actually loses a column?

Answer (score 1):

If there were a case screaming for a SQL VIEW I don't see a better one than this. Assuming your SQL back-end supports them (and I believe all worth their salt do) go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would suggest to have a normalize table structure to write easy to read/use sql [The Three Normal Forms - MySQL](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/3/)

Ensure that you columns name are descriptive to what they will be used for, for example a `userid` must not be called `custom_data_1`. If you create a new table and userid needs to be reference it should be easy to link as a foreign key.

You can store everything in one table, however Structure Query Language are there to do just that - consolidating data from different tables (optimized and created properly) into one view. The important thing to consider is scalability and maintainabilty as the data grows.

Consider MySQL best practices - [Top 20+ MySQL Best Practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/)

Also a intersting read - [Splitting Tables in MySQL. Good practice?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11990/splitting-tables-in-mysql-good-practice)